# Error 404 while sending a file using $http AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, http

I'm trying to get a file using $http, I tested my code in another application and it's working well but in my application I get this error:

[image]

this is my code:

```
app.controller("directoryCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "Restangular", "langFctr", "$translate", function($scope, $http, Restangular, langFctr, $translate) {

    $scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", files[0]);
    $http.post("/input", fd, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("ok");
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: What does your route look like on the back end?

Comment: Look at the URL, you want to access something on localhost Port 9000. Maybe there is nothing? And you are saying you want to GET a file but you are having a $http.post instead of a GET.

Comment: `{'Content-Type': undefined }` shouldn't this be `{'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }` because you're sending files to a post action? Also what are you using as your backend?

Comment: @gruberb I want to get the file in my controller but from angular I have to post it to my controller

Comment: @CallumLinington thank you for your help but it doesn't work

Comment: You will have to provide more code about your backend otherwise the question will have to be closed

Comment: Actually I do nothing in the backend and here is the function that I call http://pastebin.com/pGweYwXp and I tried the same code in another application and it's working well I don't know what is the problem

Comment: I found the problem it was because I'm using play.http.filters I don't know how to resolve this